# How to flatMap cats Applicatives

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, applicative, flatmap

I've started learning functional programming with Cats and I stuck with flatMapping (merging) applicatives `F[List]`.

What is very simple in pure Scala is flatmapping list of lists like that:

```
val animals = List("Dog", "Cat", "Bird")
def getBreads(animal: String): List[String] = ...

val allAnimalsBreads = animals.flatMap(animal => getBread(animal)) // this will be just List[String]
```

How can I do the same if everything is wrapped with applicative?:

```
val animals = List("Dog", "Cat", "Bird").pure[F]
def getBreads(animal: String): F[List[String]] = ...

val allAnimalsBreads = ? // this should be F[List[String]]
```

Comment: I am not a category theorist but I think the point of `Applicative` is that it doesn't have the ability to `flatMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Applicative](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/applicative.html) provides `ap` and `pure`, but does not guarantee to provide `flatMap`, which is provided by [Monad](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monad.html):

> `Monad` extends the `Applicative` type class with a new function `flatten`.

If `F` was a monad, then at least in scalaz we might use `ListT`, for example,

```
import scalaz._
import ListT._
import scalaz.std.option._

val animals: Option[List[String]] = Some(List("Dog", "Cat", "Bird"))
def getBreeds(animal: String): Option[List[String]] = ???

(for {
  animal <- listT(animals)
  breed <- listT(getBreeds(animal))
} yield breed).run
```

However cats does not seem to provide [ListT](https://typelevel.org/cats/faq.html#listt):

> A naive implementation of `ListT` suffers from associativity issues; ... It’s possible to create a `ListT` that doesn’t
>   have these issues, but it tends to be pretty inefficient. For many
>   use-cases, `Nested` can be used to achieve the desired results.

---

Here is an attempt at a mad solution that you should **not** use. Consider `Validated` which only has `Applicative` instance. Let us provide a `Monad` instance even though [Validated is not a Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211776/why-isnt-validation-a-monad-scalaz7):

```
implicit def validatedMonad[E]: Monad[Validated[E, *]] =
  new Monad[Validated[E, *]] {
    def flatMap[A, B](fa: Validated[E, A])(f: A => Validated[E, B]): Validated[E, B] =
      fa match {
        case Valid(a) => f(a)
        case i @ Invalid(_) => i
      }

    def pure[A](x: A): Validated[E, A] = Valid(x)

    def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: A => Validated[E, Either[A, B]]) = ???
  }
```

The implementation of `validatedMonad` is taken from [scala-exercises.org/cats/validated](https://www.scala-exercises.org/cats/validated).

Next let us make scalaz's `listT` available within cats via [shims](https://github.com/djspiewak/shims) interop layer

```
libraryDependencies += "com.codecommit" %% "shims" % "2.1.0"
```

Putting it all together, we have

```
import cats._
import cats.Monad
import cats.data.Validated.{Invalid, Valid}
import cats.data.{Nested, OptionT, Validated, ValidatedNec}
import cats.implicits._
import scalaz.ListT._
import shims._

implicit def validatedMonad[E]: Monad[Validated[E, *]] =
  new Monad[Validated[E, *]] {
    def flatMap[A, B](fa: Validated[E, A])(f: A => Validated[E, B]): Validated[E, B] =
      fa match {
        case Valid(a) => f(a)
        case i @ Invalid(_) => i
      }

    def pure[A](x: A): Validated[E, A] = Valid(x)

    def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: A => Validated[E, Either[A, B]]) = ???
  }

val animals: Validated[String, List[String]] = List("Dog", "Cat", "Bird").valid
def getBreeds(animal: String): Validated[String, List[String]] = ???

(for {
  animal <- listT(animals)
  breed <- listT(getBreeds(animal))
} yield breed).run
```

Note this "solution" breaks monadic laws, is not general, and is likely to cause confusion, so do not use it.

Comment: For `ListT` `F` must be a `Monad`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Do you mind reviewing my mad "solution" for `Validated` applicative.

Comment: `Validated` has `andThen` which is basically the "monadic" `flatMap` operation.

Answer (score 2):

For `Applicative` this is impossible. For `Monad` if you don't want to use unconventional transformer `ListT` you can do

```
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.syntax.applicative._
import cats.syntax.functor._
import cats.syntax.flatMap._
import cats.instances.list._

val allAnimalsBreads: F[List[String]] =
  animals.map(_.map(getBreads)) // F[List[F[List[String]]]]
    .map(_.sequence) // F[F[List[List[String]]]]
    .flatten // F[List[List[String]]]
    .map(_.flatten) // F[List[String]]
```